# Как можно сократить подобный код или вовсе от него избавится?

Tags: c#, wpf

Имею ряд кнопок, которые переключают страницу приложения. У кнопок есть 2 состояния, нажатая и нет, для каждого состояния реализован стиль `Menu` - обычная и `MenuIn` - нажатая (то есть у пользователя открыта сейчас именно эта страница). В стилях изменяется только цвет.

Сейчас у меня каждая кнопка привязана к обработчику, который с помощью `switch`, по названию кнопки выполняет необходимые действия, а именно открывает нужную страницу, задает всем не активным кнопкам стиль `Menu` и кнопке текущего раздела задает стиль `MenuIn`. В итоге у меня получается огромная портянка повторяющихся строк.

Как грамотно сократить код, может в стиле как то определять нажата кнопка или нет, может еще что?

---

```
private void ButtonEvent(string name)
        {
            switch (name)
            {
                case "ChangeBg":
                    BackgroundEvent.Restart();
                    break;
                case "HomeBtn":
                    HomeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["MenuIn"];
                    NewsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    AlertsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    InvasionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    SettingsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    InfoBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    TradeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    ActMissionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    MainFrame.Navigate(new Uri("View/HomePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "NewsBtn":
                    HomeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    NewsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["MenuIn"];
                    AlertsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    InvasionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    SettingsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    InfoBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    TradeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    ActMissionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    //MyPopup.IsOpen = true;
                    MainFrame.Navigate(new Uri("View/NewsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "AlertsBtn":
                    HomeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    NewsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    AlertsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["MenuIn"];
                    InvasionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    SettingsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    InfoBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    TradeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    ActMissionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    //MyPopup.IsOpen = false;
                    //BodyFrame.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/AlertsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "TradeBtn":
                    HomeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    NewsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    AlertsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    InvasionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    SettingsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    InfoBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    TradeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["MenuIn"];
                    ActMissionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    //BodyFrame.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/TradePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "InvasionsBtn":
                    HomeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    NewsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    AlertsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    InvasionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["MenuIn"];
                    SettingsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    InfoBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    TradeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    ActMissionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    //BodyFrame.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/InvasionsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "InfoBtn":
                    HomeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    NewsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    AlertsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    InvasionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    SettingsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    InfoBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["MenuIn"];
                    TradeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    ActMissionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    //BodyFrame.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/InfoPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "SettingsBtn":
                    HomeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    NewsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    AlertsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    InvasionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    InfoBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    SettingsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["MenuIn"];
                    TradeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    ActMissionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    //BodyFrame.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/SettingsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "ActMissionsBtn":
                    HomeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    NewsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    AlertsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    InvasionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    InfoBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    SettingsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    TradeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
                    ActMissionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["MenuIn"];
                    //BodyFrame.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/ActiveMissionsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
            }
        }
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `HomeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources[name == "HomeBtn" ? "MenuIn" : "Menu"];`

Comment: не уверен, что правильно понял вопрос, но разве такую задачу нельзя решить обычным стилем?

Comment: мне кажется, вашу задачу можно решить намного проще, у вас есть возможность добавить скриншот?

Comment: @PetSerAl Вариант довольно хороший, приму на вооружение если не найдется получше.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Вот я и спрашиваю как) Я на данный момент реализовал это двумя разными стилями, знаю что у Button есть несколько типов, один из которых вроде зажат/отжат, но как грамотно с этим работать так и не понял. Скрин сейчас сделаю.

Comment: Добавил скриншот меню.

Comment: почему просто не оформить меню в виде `ItemsControl`? Есть отличная статья о том, как можно организовать навигацию, [ссылка](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)

Comment: возможно, вместо `ItemsControl` лучше будет использовать `ListBox`, там реализован функционал `SelectedItem`

Comment: @FoggyFinder Хорошо, как тогда в `ListBox`'е реализовать подобное расположение кнопок? Ведь у меня 2 (маленькие) кнопки вверху имеют другое расположение, а также две кнопки снизу, отделенные от всех основных. Лист получится мне все это сложит построчно (что мне не нужно)

Comment: @FoggyFinder А по поводу того, что по ссылке (спасибо за нее конечно) - таким методом мне придется писать еще отдельно класс для всего этого, что в итоге увеличит код в полтора раза как минимум...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62023/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and-evgeniyz).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, а один вариант всегда должен быть выбран?

Comment: @Vlad да, это некий аналог вкладок, где одна должна всегда быть выбрана (текущая страница), а последующие наоборот.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, а RadioButton не подойдет?

Comment: @Vlad ну если их можно расположить "подобным" образом, как на скриншоте (несколько сверху, несколько снизу), то может быть.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это выглядит неправильно семантически.

Во-первых, каждая кнопка должна быть ответственна за *себя*, посторонний код не должен быть нужен.

Затем, скорее всего у вас не должно быть разных *стилей* для разных состояний кнопки. Для того, чтобы поменять изображение, просто примените триггер. Нужные куски информации для триггера положите в attached property.

В результате получится что-то такое

```
<Style TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Key="MenuButton">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="24"/> <!-- или сколько там надо -->
    <!-- остальные свойства -->
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
            <!-- и так далее -->
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Необходимость в `ButtonEvent` отпадает.

---

Для того, чтобы набор `ToggleButton`'ов вёл себя как `RadioButton`'ы, можно взять `RadioButton`'ы и застилизовать их:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Key="MenuButton"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
            <!-- остальная часть стиля -->
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="30">
        <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}" GroupName="First"/>
        <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}" GroupName="First"/>
        <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}" GroupName="First"/>
        <Grid Height="10"/>
        <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}" GroupName="Second"/>
        <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}" GroupName="Second"/>
        <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}" GroupName="Second"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

---

Чтобы привязать команды к каждой кнопке, я бы сделал так. Во-первых, в `DataContext`'е (то есть, VM) положил бы коллекцию команд.

Вместо ручного создания кнопок взял бы `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}" GroupName="First"
                         Command="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

По нажатию кнопки вызывалась бы команда, а она уж пусть решает, что делать дальше.

Если ваш контрол — на самом деле `ToolBar`, вы можете использовать `ToolBar` вместо `ItemsControl`'а.

```
<ToolBarTray Orientation="Vertical">
    <ToolBar ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}" GroupName="First"
                             Command="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

Comment: Попробовал по данному примеру, создал проект WPF, в `Window.Resources` добавил указанный вами код, создал 3 кнопки ToggleButton и привязал их к стилю. Получилось, что они не меняли у меня цвет на тот, что указано в тригере. Ну с этим ладно, разобраться можно. Другой вопрос - как тогда мне другим кнопкам убирать `IsChecked` при нажатие на одну из? Ведь мне не нужно что бы все кнопки были выделены.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Попробуйте вот такой трюк: https://pastebin.com/G65jTZ54

Comment: Во, вот это прям похоже то, что нужно. Как теперь их грамотно заставить открывать необходимую страницу? Вешать всех на одно событие Checked или для каждого разное? Как я понимаю, можно и на одно событие, где по имени определить какую страницу открыть, но вы вроде говорите этого делать не стоит. Так как быть?)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, мне кажется, что вам нужно было кастомизировать TabControl, а не кнопки.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Дописал ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать засунуть все кнопки в коллекцию `myButtons`, тогда получается что-то вроде:

```
private void ButtonEvent(string name)
{
    if (name == "ChangeBg")
    {
        BackgroundEvent.Restart()
        return;
    }

    var myButtons = new[] { HomeBtn, NewsBtn, AlertsBtn, InvasionsBtn,
                            SettingsBtn, InfoBtn, TradeBtn, ActMissionsBtn };

    foreach(var element in myButtons)
    {
        if (element.Name == name)
            element.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["MenuIn"];
        else
            element.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
    }

    BodyFrame.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/" + name.Substring(0, name.Length - 3) + "Page.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

**UPD**: Как правильно заметил @Андрей, было бы намного лучше где-нибудь написать что-то вроде:

```
readonly Style MenuInStyle = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["MenuIn"];
readonly Style MenuStyle = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"]
```

Тогда код становится понятнее:

```
private void ButtonEvent(string name)
{
    if (name == "ChangeBg")
    {
        BackgroundEvent.Restart()
        return;
    }

    var myButtons = new[] { HomeBtn, NewsBtn, AlertsBtn, InvasionsBtn,
                            SettingsBtn, InfoBtn, TradeBtn, ActMissionsBtn };

    foreach(var element in myButtons)
    {
        if (element.Name == name)
            element.Style = MenuInStyle;
        else
            element.Style = MenuStyle;
    }

    BodyFrame.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/" + name.Substring(0, name.Length - 3) + "Page.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но проходить циклом по элементам, это вроде "не есть хорошо", или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Никогда не слышал ничего подобного. По сути "пройтись циклом по всем элементам" не отличается от "одинаково обработать каждый элемент".

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Всегда пожалуйста!

Comment: Теперь, когда стили сохранены по переменным, самое время воспользоваться тернарным оператором! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
private void ButtonEvent(string name)
        {
            HomeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
            NewsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
            AlertsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
            InvasionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
            SettingsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
            InfoBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
            TradeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
            ActMissionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["Menu"];
            switch (name)
            {
                case "ChangeBg":
                    BackgroundEvent.Restart();
                    break;
                case "HomeBtn":
                    HomeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["MenuIn"];
                    MainFrame.Navigate(new Uri("View/HomePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "NewsBtn":
                    NewsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["MenuIn"];
                    MainFrame.Navigate(new Uri("View/NewsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "AlertsBtn":
                    AlertsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["MenuIn"];
                    BodyFrame.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/AlertsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "TradeBtn":
                    TradeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["MenuIn"];
                    BodyFrame.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/TradePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "InvasionsBtn":
                    InvasionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["MenuIn"];
                    BodyFrame.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/InvasionsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "InfoBtn":
                    InfoBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["MenuIn"];
                    BodyFrame.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/InfoPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "SettingsBtn":
                    SettingsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["MenuIn"];
                    BodyFrame.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/SettingsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
                case "ActMissionsBtn":
                    ActMissionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["MenuIn"];
                    BodyFrame.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/ActiveMissionsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                    break;
            }
        }
```

*(Update)* А вот такой пример подойдет?

```
private void ButtonEvent(string name)
        {
            if (name == "ChangeBg") {
                BackgroundEvent.Restart();
                return;
            }
            HomeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources[name != "HomeBtn" ? "Menu" : "MenuIn"];
            NewsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources[name != "NewsBtn" ? "Menu" : "MenuIn"];
            AlertsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources[name != "AlertsBtn" ? "Menu" : "MenuIn"];
            InvasionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources[name != "InvasionsBtn" ? "Menu" : "MenuIn"];
            SettingsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources[name != "SettingsBtn" ? "Menu" : "MenuIn"];
            InfoBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources[name != "InfoBtn" ? "Menu" : "MenuIn"];
            TradeBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources[name != "TradeBtn" ? "Menu" : "MenuIn"];
            ActMissionsBtn.Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources[name != "ActMissionsBtn" ? "Menu" : "MenuIn"];
            BodyFrame.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/" + name.Substring(0, name.Length - 3) + "Page.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я думаю, что это поменять "шило на мыло", да сократит пару строк, но сам код остается длинной портянкой.

Comment: Спасибо, второй вариант уже получше.

Comment: Меня одного смущает, что вы в каждой строчке лезете в `(Style) Application.Current.Resources[...`? Неужели нельзя сохранить в переменную и обращаться к ней, читабельность возрастет в разы - не нужно в каждой строке всматриваться в параметр индексатора (а точно он здесь такой же что и в предыдущей строке, одним из символов не отличается?) @EvgeniyZ

Comment: Ну и для того чтобы помочь компилятору помогать вам необходимо сохранить имена ресурсов в константу и работать уже с ней. Тут вы уже не опечатаетесь в символе - код просто не скомпилируется...

Comment: @Андрей Ну вот я и спрашиваю советов) Не могли бы вы написать 
 простой пример того, как и что сохранять и обращаться?