# Получить доступ к элементу в ItemsControl по его индексу WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно получить доступ к кнопке в ItemsControl по индексу. Например у меня есть 100 записей и я хочу получить экземпляр 5-й кнопки, чтобы мог менять её как захочу. Исходный xaml:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="mainList">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="40" Margin="1 1 2 3">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Button x:Name="Button" Tag="{Binding}" Click="Button_Click">
                    <Image Source="/Resources/button.png"></Image>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Хочу работать с кнопкой Button и вложенной в нее картинкой. Важно, чтобы не нужно было событие типа Click, где передается объект, а доставать из самого mainList по типу mainList[5].Button...

Comment: Если вас ответ не устроил, зачем вы его приняли здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/710803/218063 Вы по сути задаёте тот же вопрос. Конкретно что вы хотите менять у пятой кнопки? Зачем вы используете ItemsControl, если вам в итоге нужна коллекция кнопок? Ну так генерируйте тогда коллекцию вручную и помещайте кнопки, например, в StackPanel.

Comment: @Андрей, я посмотрел ваш ответ, он как я понял верный, у меня пока недостаточно знаний и я его не до конца понял + надо переделывать все с нуля, а я пишу код пока просто, чтобы он просто заработал хоть как-то. Может можно как-то через Binding просто привязать переменную в которой будет храниться состояние. Извиняюсь за свою некомпетентность, даже не понял, что за классы VM и RelayCommand и для чего они нужны...

Comment: @Max WPF не работает так, что "Дай мне 5-ый элемент, я хочу что бы заместо строки у меня там бабочки летали". Вы делаете коллекцию, у которой четкая структура данных, ее привязываете к окну или самому объекту как `DataSource`, а в `XAML` задаете объекты, которые с помощью `Binding`'a привязываете к нужному объекту в той коллекции, которую привязали. Все, дальше вы не работаете с объектами (кнопками и др), вы работаете с коллекцией. К примеру надо изменить Play на Pause, картинку, вы создаете в классе коллекции элемент, который будет содержать в себе ссылку на картинку. Вот дальше его меняете.

Comment: Вы не будете писать `ListBox1.Items[5].Picture = "Play.png"`, в `WPF` такой подход просто неверен. Вы должны писать `MyList[5].Picture = "Play.png"`, где `MyList`, это некая коллекция, `ObservableCollection<T>`, которая привязана к элементу `ListBox1`. С самим `ListBox1` по сути вы не должны взаимодействовать. Да и то, что я пишу не совсем верно.. Вам в том ответе все четко написали и такое должно быть у вас изначально, ибо дальше ваше приложение превратиться в некое непонятное существо! Почитайте про `Binding`, про `INotifyPropertyChanged` и про `MVVM` в частности.

Comment: Вам не должно хотеться получать элемент по индексу практически никогда. Индекс UI-контрола вообще не нужен, а вместо индекса VM-элемента передавайте сам VM-элемент.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите получать контрол по индексу, то что вам нужно - это использовать VisualTreeHelper. Следующий пример демонстрирует как делать невидимым элемент Label, который находится внутри объекта Button.  Я заменил Image на Label, но сути это не меняет.
XAML

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="mainList">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="40" Margin="1 1 2 3">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Button x:Name="Button1" Tag="{Binding}" >
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Caption}"></Label>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
    <Button x:Name="Button2" Tag="{Binding}" Click="Button2_Click">
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Код внутри дефолтного класса MainWindow: Window . Основными методами здесь являются  FindContolsByType и FindButtonLabelByIndex

```
 public class Element
    {            
        public string Caption { get; set; }            
    }

    public List<Element> Items;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items = GetElemetns();
        mainList.ItemsSource = Items;
    }

    private Control FindButtonLabelByIndex(int index)
    {
        // Здесь можно легко заменить Label на Image или другой тип
        var controls = FindContolsByType(mainList as DependencyObject, typeof(Label));
        return controls.ElementAt(index) as Control;
    }

    //Рекурсивный поиск каждого контрола нужного типа в visual tree
    private IEnumerable<DependencyObject> FindContolsByType(DependencyObject dObject, Type targetType)
    {
        var childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dObject);           
        var list = new List<DependencyObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
            var control = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dObject, i);
            if (control.GetType() == targetType)
            {
                list.Add(control);
            }
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control) > 0)
            {
                 list.AddRange(FindContolsByType(control, targetType));                    
            }                                    
        }

        return list;
    }

    private List<Element> GetElemetns()
    {
        return new List<Element>
        {
            new Element{Caption = "B1"}, new Element{Caption = "B2"}
        };
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = FindButtonLabelByIndex(1);
        control.Visibility = control.Visibility != Visibility.Hidden ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
    }
```