# wpf mvvm async Как сохранить состояние view и передать параметр MainWindow

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Есть программа, слева меню, справа открывается view. На `View`, при нажатии кнопки, запускается задача и работает `ProgressBar`. Для  этого я использую `Task`, чтобы менялся `ProgressBar` на лету. Дальше я дошел (я новичок) до `async` и все хорошо. Но теперь я бы хотел, чтобы переключаясь через окна пока работает `Task`, `ProgressBar` не обнулялся бы, т.к. задача ещё работает. Но `ProgressBar` не обновляется. И еще хотел бы, чтобы на кнопке в меню крутился круглый `ProgressBar`, чтобы клиент понимал, что работает программа.

Но как из `ViewModel` передать параметр `MainWindow`?

ProgressBar это отдельный UserControl который я помещаю во View.

```
<ProgressBar Value="{Binding CurrentProgress}" Margin="10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="15" Width="780"/>
```

CurrentProgress обернутый в Task async метод берет количество делит на сто и увеличивается на 1 во время цикла. Это все работает.

Подробнее:

Wpf MVVM

Есть программа основное окно слева кнопки справа UserControl. Кнопка меню код

```
 DataContext = new ImportContractUslViewModel();
```

[image: Пример]

На этом UserControl располагается еще один UserControlProgressBar с кодом

```
   <ProgressBar Value="{Binding CurrentProgress}" Margin="10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="15" Width="780"/>
```

ViewModel

```
public double CurrentProgress
{
    get { return _currentProgress; }
    set
    {
        _currentProgress = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentProgress");
    }
}

public async void ImportPaymentsDoc() //Метод обработки
{
    inserted = 0;
    var importDoc = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var res = db.eias_PaymentDocument.Include("eias_PaymentDocument_ChargeInfo").Where(c => c.AccountGUID != null ).OrderBy(c => c.AccountGUID).Select(c => c).ToList();
        //Получаем значение из базы 
        count = res.Count; // Считаем кол-во записей
        foreach (var ty in res)
        {
            //Код обработки записей ...

            inserted++;
            updateProgress(inserted);

        }
    });

    await importDoc;

    importDoc.Wait();
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(importDoc.Status.ToString());
}

//Метод подсчета значений прогресс бар

private  void updateProgress(int Analyzed)
{
    if (Analyzed != 0)
    {
        int percentage = 100 * Analyzed / count;
        CurrentProgress = percentage;
    }
}
```

После того как я запускаю операцию обработки прогресс бар начинает считать проценты все ок но стоит мне перейти в другой DataContext задача выполняется дальше проверено ждет завершения но я бы хотел что бы прогресс бар не обнулялся.
А так же как повесить Круглый прогресс бар на кнопку меню не забудем MVVM. Что бы пользователь мог лазить по программе и видел что задача например Квитанции выполняется и знал когда завершилась что бы можно было обратно перейти и нажать следующую кнопку.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65822/discussion-between--and--).

Comment: Андрей разобрался конечно не до конца но пока сделал так

Comment: MainWindows.xaml Добавил  <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodels:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

Comment: Потом там же добавил 2  <ContentControl x:Name="cc" Content="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding  ImportPaymentsDocVM}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="105,0,0,0" Foreground="{x:Null}"   />
        <ContentControl x:Name="cc2" Content="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding ExportNSIVM}"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="105,0,0,0" Foreground="{x:Null}"   />

Comment: На кнопку повесил  cc2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            cc.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

Comment: Криво пока но зато проверил действительно работает ProgressBar. ContentControl хотелось бы один.

Comment: Как стилизовать радиобатон в кнопку можно посмотреть в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691259/218063

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы каждый раз создаете новый экземпляр VM:

> ```
> DataContext = new ImportContractUslViewModel();
> ```

У него естественно свой экземпляр свойства `CurrentProgress`, который по умолчанию и равен 0.

Решение - создавать VM один раз и всегда использовать только этот единственный экземпляр.