# Не могу поместить кнопку на панель в форме WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Вот код:

```xml
<DockPanel x:Name="panelButtonsLeftMenu"
           Background="#E6EBEF"
           Height="770" Margin="0,30,791,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="219">
    <DockPanel x:Name="panelLogo" Height="100" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="219">
        <Label Content="LOGO" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="219" FontSize="48" FontFamily="SF Pro Display" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel Height="468" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Margin="0,302,0,0"/>
</DockPanel>

<DockPanel x:Name="pnlBtnItem1" DockPanel.Dock="Top"
           Width="219" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,129,0,0" LastChildFill="False" Height="17" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
<DockPanel x:Name="panelButtonsLeftMenu_Copy"
           Background="#F6F6F6"
           Height="770" Margin="219,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <DockPanel x:Name="panelLogo1" Height="100" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="219"/>
    <DockPanel Height="468" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Margin="0,302,0,0"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Отмечу, что на WPF перешел недавно, еще одна проблема к уже имеющейся — кнопка, которую пытался разместить до этого, оказалась под панелью...

 В общем набыдлокодил, прошу помощи, коллеги :)

Прикрепил пример, как должно быть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ам, в где собственно кнопка(где она должна быть) ? и почему не можете ?

Comment: 1. Уберите все x:Name, в wpf так не делают! Научитесь делать привязки. 2. Почему DockPanel? 3. Не используйте дизайнер для составления UI, его можно только для просмотра использовать, не более, ибо он вам генерирует много лишнего.

Comment: Какой результат хотите получить? Куда кнопку надо вставить?

Comment: @aepot да вот хочу сделать кнопки меню на панели.
Получается схема такая на панели есть кнопки, которые тоже на панельках под кнопки сделанные.

Comment: Как у вас так получилось объяснить, что я ничего не понял? Можете хотя-бы картинку нарисовать с вашим интерфейсом? Или скриншот интерфейса, где вы вручную выставили все что нужно в дизайнере. Ну и пару слов, как это должно работать.

Comment: @aepot прикрепил картинку. Этот пример сделал на обычном Win Application.
Получается что тут под кажду кнопку подложена панель такого-же размера и сами кнопки находятся на панели. Крепятся друг к другу с помощью Dock (кроме "Настройки").
Т.е лого и кнопки имеют параметр Dock = Top, а "Настройки": Dock = Bottom (это касаемо Windows Applcation), вот теперь нужно сделать похожее, только на WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так можно

```xaml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Background="LightGray">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="DockPanel">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5"/>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray"/>
                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0"/>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <StackPanel SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Ellipse Width="40" Height="40" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" Fill="Gray" Margin="10"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Пользователь" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <TextBlock Text="текст пользователя"/>
                <DockPanel Background="White">
                    <TextBlock Text="Главная"/>
                    <Rectangle/>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Статистика"/>
                    <Rectangle/>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Календарь"/>
                    <Rectangle/>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Контакты"/>
                    <Rectangle/>
                </DockPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            <DockPanel Grid.Row="2">
                <TextBlock Text="Настройки"/>
                <Rectangle/>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="Основная часть окна"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Я показал просто XAML визуал. Сам больше склоняюсь к [MVVM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern) и технологичным решениям, например [это решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1185026/373567) мне нравится. Другими словами, состав меню должен быть списком и из чего-то формироваться, а не просто захардкожен в разметку. То есть вместо `StackPanel` будет `ListBox` или любой другой `ItemsControl`. При этом WPF позволяет изменить стиль любого контрола до неузнаваемости. А `Button` здесь не подходит.*

Comment: `А Button здесь не подходит` - почему? Наоборот, он тут необходим. Без этого компонента придется писать свои костыли на обработку клика и прочей мишуры.   Пару лет назад, когда я еще только познавал WPF, я делал подобное меню и спрашивал тут, на SO, как сократить мои попытки выделить нажатую кнопку в меню, в итоге дали [такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691259/220553) решение с дизайном кнопки и оно тут я думаю будет просто идеально) По поводу кстати IoC, попробуйте еще Prism, комбайн для WPF, который работает с IoC (да считай это его основная часть).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ мне пока Autofac хватает. Ок, кнопка подходит, но здесь можно через тот же `ListBox` решить. Реагировать не еа клик, а на изменение выбранного элемента коллекции. Как мне кажется, кликами лучше пусть контрол занимается.

Comment: А вы не сделаете через `ListBox` нижнюю кнопку, тут надо делать `ItemsControl`, который будет создавать динамически кнопки и биндить их положение, а чтобы это было неким переключением, то брать уже стилизованную `RadioButton`. Ну а так, вариантов много, да, зависит от самой задачи.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ верно, нижнюю кнопку легче через `Button`, да. Спасибо за `RadioButton`, совсем забыл про их существование, надо будет поиграться, повспоминать.