# Как правильно воспользоваться StackPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу расположить на форме пары Label + какой-нибудь Combobox.

В принципе, если располагать все через Grid, то все весьма красиво получается:

```
   <Grid >
        <Grid.Resources >
            <Style TargetType="Border" >
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,5,5,5" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">Тип БД</Label>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></ComboBox>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">База данных</Label>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></ComboBox>
        <Label Grid.Row="2">Таблица</Label>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"></ComboBox>
        <Label Grid.Row="3">Ключ таблицы</Label>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"></ComboBox>
        <Label Grid.Row="4">Значение таблицы</Label>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"></ComboBox>
        <Label Grid.Row="5">Идентификатор привязки к справочнику</Label>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"></ComboBox>
    </Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но мне не нравится то, что в разметке парные-элементы никак не группируются между собой...

Я попробовал попарно их засунуть каждый в свой StackPanel, но в итоге не все так красиво получается, как в Grid... Как я могу решить проблему, чтобы элементы занимали по 50% рабочей области окна?

Comment: Сразу замечание - выкинуть все `Label`, и использовать `TextBlock`. Причин много, не буду все перечислять. По поводу остальной разметки - [вот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1186906/373567) с использованием `DockPanel`.

Comment: @aepot комбобоксы очень узиникими становятся=( Это нужно им минимальную ширину задать или как-то процентное соотношене можно?

Comment: Если хочется красиво, то лучше тут ItemsControl с шаблоном в виде Grid, а сам список сформировать в VM. Если так и хочешь статику оставить, то используй UniformGrid. В нем задаёшь Columns="2" и в него засовывать все эти элементы без Grid.Row и Grid.Column. UniformGrid сам распихнет все элементы по ячейка в порядке их описания в Xaml. Соответственно и Grid.Definition тоже не нужны будут. Но решение так себе, как по мне.

Answer (score 0):

> Но мне не нравится то, что в разметке парные-элементы никак не группируются между собой...

Сгруппировать то легко, запихнуть каждую пару в свой Grid, да и все тут. Поведение в отношении размера стобцов у одного Grid и последовательности однострочных Grid идентично. Но, глядя на вашу разметку, смущает скорее дублирование строк и элементов. Если у вас в разметке куча однотипных пар Label + (что-то), которые ходят вместе и образуют строку таблицы, должны ли они быть отдельными элементами? По моему, это отличный повод для создания своего элемента управления.

Раз нам нужно поведение Grid в плане изменения размеров столбцов, этот элемент управления можно сделать производным от Grid:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfTest
{
    public class ControlPair : Grid
    {
        UIElement first;
        UIElement second;

        public UIElement First
        {
            get { return this.first; }
            set
            {
                this.first = value;
                UpdateChildren();
            }
        }

        public UIElement Second
        {
            get{ return this.second; }

            set
            {
                this.second = value;
                UpdateChildren();
            }
        }

        void UpdateChildren()
        {
            this.Children.Clear();

            if (this.first != null)
            {
                this.Children.Add(this.first);
                Grid.SetColumn(this.first, 0);
            }

            if (this.second != null)
            {
                this.Children.Add(this.second);
                Grid.SetColumn(this.second, 1);
            }
        }

        public ControlPair() : base()
        {
            this.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
            this.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition()
            {
                Width = new GridLength(0.5, GridUnitType.Star)
            });

            this.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition()
            {
                Width = new GridLength(0.5, GridUnitType.Star)
            });

            this.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь у элемента управления есть два свойства, First и Second, которым можно присвоить любой элемент управления. Элементы помещаются в ячейки Grid, для которых задан определенный процент доступного пространства. Тогда мы можем в разметке делать так:

```
<local:ControlPair>
    <local:ControlPair.First>
        <Label Content="Тип БД"></Label>
    </local:ControlPair.First>
    <local:ControlPair.Second>
        <ComboBox/>
    </local:ControlPair.Second>
</local:ControlPair>
```

И элементы сгруппированы, и не нужна куча RowDefinition.

Более развернутый пример, как это можно применить на практике:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest" x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        Height="250" Width="400" >
    <Grid>        
        <StackPanel>
        
            <local:ControlPair HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <local:ControlPair.First>
                    <Label Content="Тип БД"></Label>
                </local:ControlPair.First>
                <local:ControlPair.Second>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DatabaseTypeValues}"
                        Text="{Binding Path=DatabaseTypeSelected,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </local:ControlPair.Second>
            </local:ControlPair>
            
            <local:ControlPair HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <local:ControlPair.First>
                    <Label Content="База данных"></Label>
                </local:ControlPair.First>
                <local:ControlPair.Second>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Database,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </local:ControlPair.Second>
            </local:ControlPair>
            
            <Button x:Name="myButton" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="10,10,10,10" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Click="Button_Click" />

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Options optionsData;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            optionsData = new Options();
            optionsData.DatabaseTypeValues = new string[] { "SQL Server", "Access" };            
            this.DataContext = optionsData;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //show selected options
            MessageBox.Show("Selected " +
                "\nDatabaseType: " + optionsData.DatabaseTypeSelected +
                "\nDatabase: " + optionsData.Database
                );
        }
    }

    public class Options
    {
        public string[] DatabaseTypeValues { get; set; }
        public string DatabaseTypeSelected { get; set; }
        public string Database { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]