# Как создать панель кнопок

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Нужно сделать папель кнопок,логика похожа на пункт меню можно выбрить только  один пункт.
Мне нужно сделать 2 панели кнопок,мне хватит одной главное логику понять  а дальше сам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691259/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  спасибо за информацию изучу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогли ссылки  [1](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691259/220553) [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzP8mw7JUzI&ab_channel=BinaryBunny)  [3](https://github.com/cesarioalmeida/SideMenu). Впасибо за правильное @EvgeniyZ  направленные.